# Как спарсить определенное значение из тега <script> HTML кода?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Парсим данную страницу с BeautifulSoup:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests as req

url = "https://www.fl.ru/projects/"
req = req.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text , 'html5lib')
```

Выводим ленту со всеми проектами на данной странице по тегу:

```
lenta = soup.find('div', class_='b-page__lenta' )
```

Выводим один пост из всей ленты:

```
post = lenta.find('div', class_='b-post')
```

В переменной post содержатся теги: `['script', 'h2', 'img', 'a', 'script', 'div', 'script', 'div']` и мне необходим первый `<script>`

```
script = post.find('script')
```

И вот его содержание (`print`):

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write('<div class="b-post__price b-layout__txt_right b-post__price_padleft_10 b-post__price_padbot_5 b-post__price_float_right b-post__price_fontsize_15 b-post__price_bold"> <a class="b-layout__txt_fontsize_12 b-layout__txt_padright_10 b-layout__txt_color_61a22b b-layout__txt_text_decor_none b-layout__txt_bold" href="/promo/bezopasnaya-sdelka/" target="_blank" title="Оплата через Безопасную сделку"> <span class="b-icon b-icon__shield b-icon_top_2_iphone"></span>Безопасная сделка</a> 10&nbsp;000&nbsp;₽ </div>');</script>
```

Этот тег script содержит в себе еще множество тегов, но парсить далее данным методом я не могу, на вывод приходит `'None'`. BeautifulSoup воспринимает его только как `script.text`, и внутри этого текста не могу парсить далее.

Что делать? Как продолжить код, чтобы в итоге извлечь из него данное значение: `'10&nbsp;000&nbsp;₽'`?

Comment: А при помощи регулярки не хочешь вытащить нужное значение ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из тега `script` можно вытащить искомую стоимость регулярным выражением по заданному шаблону, предварительно преобразовав `script` в строку и почистить в ней "&nbsp;":

```
import re

pattern = re.compile("> (.*?)</div>")
price = re.findall(pattern, str(script)[0].replace('&nbsp;', '')
```